# Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: 127.0.0.1 is not in the cert's ( MongoDB ) in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, openssl

I wanted to install mongodb TLS because i got hacked twice in mongodb to secure my vps then i ran out for this tutorial on how to install TLS its [link](https://bustedware.com/blog/mongodb-ssl-tls-x509-authentication)

I tried to connect inside mongodb with this command

```
mongosh localhost --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/client.pem --tlsCAFile /etc/ssl/ca.pem
```

but i got this error :

```
MongoServerSelectionError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: 127.0.0.1 is not in the cert's list
```

while this was my certificate alt names:

```
openssl x509 -passin pass:password -sha256 -req -days 365 -in node1.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca_private.pem -CAcreateserial -out node1-signed.crt -extensions v3_req -extfile <(
cat << EOF
[ v3_req ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = 127.0.0.1
DNS.2 = localhost
EOF
)
```

but when i use the **--tlsAllowInvalidHostnames** it works fine and it connects to the database normally , my question is , is this normal ? or something wrong with the certificate itself also is there anyway to fix it or just use --tlsAllowInvalidHostnames ? because i wanted also to connect to mongoDB via my local pc

expected to connect to mongoDB with TLS connection with the correct Hostnames

Answer (score 1):

SAN names

```
DNS.1 = 127.0.0.1
DNS.2 = localhost
```

is a security flaw, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/255410/ramifications-of-including-localhost-in-the-subject-alternative-field-of-an-x5

You should better use the real hostname (as return by `echo $HOSTNAME` and `echo $HOSTNAME -s`) in certificate and also for your connection string.

Apart from using TLS/SSL it would be much more important to enable Authentication, see [Use SCRAM to Authenticate Clients](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-scram-client-authentication/)